# search for Duplicate Records: on Database using SQL, or on file.txt using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a 14.7 GB txt file with 4 columns and ~440 Million rows. I have to add them into my database, but I would like to make sure that I don't have duplicates.

Since I have zipcodes/city/latitude/longitude, I figured that I only need to select "distinct latitude and longitude", because there can't be 2 places with same lat AND long.

I want to know if there is a simple solution to make this duplicate's search before I add all my data to the DB.

The file is way to big to make anything with it so I split it in files of 700MB and I used:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '...\text6.txt' IGNORE
INTO TABLE zipCodes
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(zipCode, city, latitude, longitude);
```

to add each file into the DB.

Now the problem is after I added about 80M lines, if I try to make the select on the local db it's gonna take me to much time to do it and search for duplicates.

How should I do it? I'm new in this kind of work and need to learn, as much as possible and as fast as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd remove/disable the unique index before LOAD FILE for a fast import of all the data.
And after the raw import is done create/activate a new unique index via
[`ALTER IGNORE TABLE zipCodes ADD UNIQUE (latitude,longitude)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) (*mysql-specific extension).
It will (silently) drop duplicates from the table and is usually faster then constantly updating the index when inserting data while the index is active.

Comment: Oops.... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html says: `As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error.` - apparently this isn't/wasn't a good solution, see http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7395  :-( But if you're looking for a one-off trick right now  ...maybe it's feasible.

Comment: well it worked, i added over 80M lines into the DB. i'm still reading something about this right now. i don't know what would have been better ...